# How do i get sound to a gif in dreamweaver

Tags: html, attributes, dreamweaver, gif

I need help to get sound to a gif so i have fount this site which explains how to add sound to a gif but i am having trouble this is the code would anybody be able to help me get this to work i am using Dreamweaver CC here are some examples of what i am trying to get done and i'll provide the code i have done and if anyone can help me would be much appreciated

https://github.com/mahdif/loud-links/ is the Javascript used

https://loudlinks.rocks/ - Examples

```
<script src="js/loudlinks.min.js"></script></body> where have i gone wrong i've included  <script src="js/loudlinks.min.js"></script> above </body> as it has said so i dont know why it's not working.
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps at the [Loud Links GitHub](https://github.com/mahdif/loud-links/). It looks like you've only done Step 1 (including the library's JavaScript).

Also, based upon the code you've provided, your HTML is incorrectly formatted. You only want to include the script once, and all of your content should come before a single closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Firstly, you need to review StackOverflow policies regarding expletives.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233

Second, you should provide the correct code in your original question, not in a comment.

Third, your code looks correct according to the Loud Links documentation. Are you sure your audio file is located at the correct path in relation to your HTML document?

Comment: It says If you want to use Loud Links, you need to create a folder named sounds in your website’s root directory. Within this folder, create two more folders named mp3 and ogg.

After integrating the JavaScript into your HTML document the usual way, mark the links of other elements that you want to add sound to with the class loud-link-hover or loud-link-click. Using the HTML5 data attribute, you can add the specific sound without entering the file extension. This means, instead of sound.mp3, you only need to enter sound.